# applying ucfirst() on a text form field globally but before doctrine event

Tags: forms, symfony, normalization

I have a form field used on several forms in my application.
I need to force it to be ucfirst()'d, everywhere.
What is the best way to accomplish this ?

I can't use doctrine prePersist/preUpdate event, because this field value is also pushed into another entity, via an event dispatched way before the persistance, and I want this pushed value to be already transformed at this time.

I thought I could use a DataTransformer instead, but in my mind, DataTransformers are for bi-directionnal operations (transform/reverse- transform). In this case, there is no reverse-transform needed. So it might a bad use of DataTransformer.

Is there any other solution to globally perform this normalization ?

Comment: You could put the `ucfirst` in your entity setter.

Comment: this is probably the best use of the KISS principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). I'm ashamed I didn't even think of it. You can transform your comment as an answer and i'll be glad to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Use ucfirst() in your Entity setters. For example:

```
...
public function setFirstname($fname){
    $first = ucfirst($fname);
    $this->first_name = $first;

    return $this;
}
```

That should work. But then you have to modify ALL your Entities.

But I wonder if it's easier to do this:

```
$user->setFirstName( ucfirst( $form->get('first_name')->getData() ) );
```

Maybe that's a second option?